# Splicing Text In A Line (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm not too familiar with HTML/CSS and I was curious if there is any way to do splicing or any options of hiding the hyphens between year, month and day in the following string that gets generated by another program:

```
TEXT1-TEXT2-2021-09-10-001
```

That string gets automatically wrapped into the following HTML tags:

```html
<p style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 18.667px;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Request Number:</strong></span> TEXT1-TEXT2-2021-09-10-001</p>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can make use of JavaScript to do text manipulation.

Comment: there is no way with html / css to manipulate strings. You could use JS as allready suggested or if you have access to the output of the other program, before it is shown as hmtl, you coul manipulate it there

Comment: Do you just want to hide the hyphens, not substitute them with say a space or another character?

Comment: Please see updated answer. I missed it was only between yyyy mm dd you wanted to hide the dashes

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use CSS to hide them We need to use JavaScript

Because of the inconvenient structure it is not even trivial

```js
let p = document.querySelector("p");
let textNode = p.childNodes[1];  // the textNode
let text = textNode.textContent; // the text
p.replaceChild(
  document
    .createTextNode(
      text.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/,'$1 $2 $3')
    )
,textNode)
```

```html
<p style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 18.667px;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Request Number:</strong></span> TEXT1-TEXT2-2021-09-10-001</p>
```